# "for json auto" and "for json path" give syntax error in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, ssms

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18, I want to view SQL output in JSON format, but the query is not working.

```
select * from tablename for json auto
```

or

```
select * from tablename for json path
```

Gives this error:

```
: Incorrect syntax near 'FOR'. (103010) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Comment: So that other people can find this question, you should include the exact text of the error message you receive (this is also important if you're hoping for someone else to look into the problem for you).

Comment: I have updated the question, thanks :)

Comment: @IMSoP, please up vote the question

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

as per this, ssms has for json path enabled in latest version as well